# Possibly unknown number of nested for loops. How best to tackle this?

Tags: python

I have a list and dictionary structure as follows:

```
groups = [{"groupname":"group1", "groupusers":["user1","user2","user3"], "nestedgroups":["group3", "group2", "group4"]},{"groupname":"group3", "groupusers":["user2","user8","user3"], "nestedgroups":["group10", "group2", "group40"]},{"groupname":"group2", "groupusers":["user2","user8","user3"], "nestedgroups":["group1", "group2", "group40"]}]
```

I need to iterate through the list and for each entry find the nested groups of each groupname, in turn finding the nestedgroups for each nested group in nestedgroups.
I'd like it to return another key to the dictionary, so it might be something like:

```
[{groupname:"group1", groupusers:"[user1,user2,user3....]", nestedgroups:"[group2, group3, group4....]", allnestedgroups:"[group21, group42, group3, group220...]}...
```

I keep trying this with for loops but am getting stuck with the unknown amount of nesting.

I've tried something like:

```py
groups = [{"groupname":"group1", "groupusers":["user1","user2","user3"], "nestedgroups":["group3", "group2", "group4"]},{"groupname":"group3", "groupusers":["user2","user8","user3"], "nestedgroups":["group10", "group2", "group40"]},{"groupname":"group2", "groupusers":["user2","user8","user3"], "nestedgroups":["group1", "group2", "group40"]}]

for g in groups:
    allnested = []
    nested = g["nestedgroups"]
    allnested.append(nested)
    for n in nested:
        # Get the index of the nested group
        groupindex = next((index for (index, groupname) in enumerate(groups) if groupname["groupname"] == n), None)
        level2nesting = groups[groupindex]["nestedgroups"]
        allnested.append(level2nesting)
        for l2 in level2nesting:
            groupindex = next((index for (index, groupname) in enumerate(groups) if groupname["groupname"] == l2), None)
            level3nesting = groups[groupindex]["nestedgroups"]
            allnested.append(level3nesting)
```

but I'm stuck. I know there's an obvious way to programmatically handle this, but it's just not coming to me. The nesting isn't actually potentially infinite, but it could be 2 levels deep, it could be 20, or 200.

I already have logic further up the chain that should stop any actual infinite looping where the group might find itself in a nested group and loop from there.

I'd very much appreciate any advice on offer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally hierarchical processing can be implemented through recursion.

Comment: @PM77-1 - yes that's the kind of thing I'm looking for.